# How to use the .wav audio files in jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wav, jplayer

i have the problem with .wav audio files in jPlayer.,How to resolve this...it doesn't work for me...the other file formats are working like audio/mpeg but it doesn't working when audio/x-wav format...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-media-encoding) on the jPlayer website documentation:

> The WAV format is supported by many HTML5 browsers. We recommend that
>   you avoid it though as a counterpart format. The recommended encoding
>   options are:
>
> - 8-bit and 16-bit linear PCM
> - Only codec "1" (PCM) is supported.

Make sure you have it encoded right and that you are testing on a browser that supports HTML5 and WAV.